# Converting a CSV to RDF where I can't find appropriate URIs online for the subjects

Tags: uri, rdf, iri

I'm trying to convert a sanskrit dictionary from CSV format to RDF. The problem is that I cannot find appropriate URIs for the sanskrit words online. Is there a solution for this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that no 'appropriate' URIs exist for words (or any other type of data). In such cases you could think of your own URIs.

Comment: ok, i could think of my own URI, but in order for it to be of any use, I'd need to create a website that hosts the URI, correct?

Comment: To be able to reason with your data, you can treat URIs like you would treat identifier numbers: as identifiers that identify something. In this case it isn't necessary to make them *resolvable* by hosting data at those URIs. If you want to provide Linked Data, it would be helpful to return data when you dereference the URIs, so that people (or machines) can follow the links.